# Using WCF Data Services with Windows Applications

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wcf, wcf-data-services

Does it make sense to use WCF Data Services in a normal Windows applications (Winforms or WPF) or are this technology only suitable for web- or Silverlight applications?

What are the advantages in comparison to normal WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really personal preference in any case, frankly.  The only real difference between Data Services an "regular" services is that Data Services make some conventions-based assumptions about your transport and data format.  If using a RESTful service makes sense to you (which is true for almost all services where the key operations are data querying or manipulation functions), then yes.  If you have more workflow-oriented operations, then maybe not (maybe, b/c RESTful services can still represent workflows if they want to, it's just not their normally accepted strength).

Comment: WCF Data Services expose metadata for REST - that's quite a big improvement over "run-of-the-mill" REST services which have no metadata whatsoever.... this allows the client-side proxy generation for a nice, clean experience.

Comment: Sure, but I think the OP hadn't even decided on whether he wanted REST services or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these video series that shows you a Full Stack of technologies employed to build a orthogonal application architecture.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-Full-Stack

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting to be on cloud in the future, you are taking the right step. 
If in future you foresee a scenario where products from different technology can use this data service. This may be the right step.